# Does WildFly have an equivalent of loose applications from Liberty?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, wildfly, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

Open Liberty and WebSphere Liberty both support [loose applications](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=liberty-loose-applications), where instead of a WAR application you have an XML file that points to various class and jar files on the local filesystem. This can greatly speed up development, because Liberty can work directly from the target folder and the local maven repository. Combined with hot deploy it means that every change only takes seconds to appear on the web server. At the moment I am working with Wildfly, and I am sorely missing loose applications. Is there any feature that is the equivalent of them, or is there any possibility to emulate them in Wildfly? I would be especially curious if it is possible in a containerized environment such as Docker.

Comment: What kind of build system are you using?

Comment: Have you tried an exploded war?  There isn't any reason to create a full war file and in at least IntelliJ and Wildfly it's a nearly instant reload.  Debugging in Docker isn't something I've done and I don't understand what you want there.

Comment: If you are happy with OpenLiberty, whats the point to switching to WildFly?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins We use Maven, and we copy the resulting WAR file into a Docker container with WildFly 26 on it.

Comment: @stdunbar Could you elaborate on this exploded WAR, it sounds suspiciously similar to a loose application?

Comment: @Gas Wildfly is used at my new workplace.

Comment: You could use the `org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin` and the `dev` goal, https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin/dev-mojo.html. I need to do a new release to fully getting it to work with Docker, but I can do that today.